# suspend Kotlin Coroutine while waiting for the next value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Is there a way to suspend while waiting for the next value of a MutableStateFlow?

```
    val state = MutableStateFlow<Int>(1)

    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var counter = 1
        while (true) {
            state.emit(counter++)
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        while (state.value < 1000) {
            print(state.value)
            delay(250)
        }
    }
```

Currently this is printing `111122223333444...` but I want it to print `1234...`

Use-case: I'm building a driver; I have one coroutine that continuously read data being received from the socket which updates the connection status.

If I want to send data, I need to first check if the status is IDLE, if not, wait until the status is IDLE before writing data.

A very crude way to do it would be to do

```
while (state.value != 100) { delay(100) }
```

But this will perform poorly.

What I want to do, is when I retrieve the value from the state, it should get the last value without suspending; if the value is the correct value, break out of the loop, otherwise suspend until the value changes and only if the value is correct, break out of the while loop, otherwise continue to suspend until the value changes again.

It's possible using a mutex, unlock the mutex when writing a new value, lock the mutex when reading it again and that while loop will suspend until the value changes again, but it would be nice to use something off-the-shelf so to speak.

```
        var counter = 1
        val mutex = Mutex(locked = true)

        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            while (true) {
                counter++
                mutex.unlock()
                delay(100)
            }
        }

        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            while (true) {
                if (counter > 100) {
                    break
                }
                println(counter)
                mutex.lock()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just do `state.first { it >= 1000 }` ?

Comment: Or `collect` the state flow and cancel once the counter reaches 1000?

Comment: This is what flows are for. You collect them to get triggered on each emission reactively instead of you having to manually poll them for new values.

Comment: @Pawel, that `state.first { it == IDLE }` works exactly how I wanted it to work; I overlooked that while trying to get `state.first()  == IDLE` to work

Will accept that as the correct answer

Comment: @Slaw, that flow can never be cancelled, it should run for as long as the application is running. This requirement means anything that depends on the flow ending, will never end.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply you should cancel the state flow; I meant you should cancel the `collect` coroutine (i.e., by calling `cancel` on the `CoroutineScope` given to the lambda you pass to `launch`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using flow methods at all - just transform and collect the flow instead of inventing weird loops.

```
state
    .takeWhile { it < 1000 }
    .collect { print(it) }
```

Or if you don't need to print each value you can suspend in one line:

```
state.first { it >= 1000 }
```

Comment: `state.first { it == IDLE }` is perfect, it "blocks" until the the state is IDLE which is exactly what I've been looking for